# Palantir Pipeline Builder Video tutorials or online course

Tags: palantir-foundry

Hello Great Analytics folks. For my personal analytics learning, I usually go to Udemey and buy a course then walk through the whole tools or technologies to learn it. Then for the time being by working, I improve my efficiency.

Do you guys recommend any video tutorials/ courses for the PB?

Appreciate your thoughts.

Thanks

I got only 1 video on Youtube from a guy who is ex-Palantir named Taylor. His video is very helpful to me and my learning. I want more videos like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can find learning and training materials at https://learn.palantir.com/page/foundry-learning-paths

Answer (score 1):

Palantir has a good "Data Engineering Learning Path for Pipeline Builder" at https://learn.palantir.com/path/data-engineering.